# Books for the Finite Dimensional Normed Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, frame-theory

In the current semester, I am crediting a course "Finite Frames". There we are studying everything on finite-dimensional separable Hilbert space. In finite-dimensional, there are some results which are by default true (in some sense) like every subspace is closed in the finite-dimensional etc. Please suggest to me some self-study books on the finite-dimensional normed space.

Comment: What do you mean by "finite-dimensional complete Hilbert space"? In the terminology I know, every Hilbert space is complete by definition, and every finite-dimensional vector space (over a complete field, anyway) is complete.

Comment: Studying finite-dimensional normed spaces is the same as doing multivariable calculus. If $(X, \Vert \cdot \Vert)$ is a finite-dimensional normed space, then pick your favourite isomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow X$ (with $n=\dim_\mathbb{R}(X)$) and consider the norm $$ \Vert x \Vert_\varphi := \Vert \varphi(x) \Vert $$  on $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is equivalent to study $(\mathbb{R}^n, \Vert \cdot \Vert_\varphi)$ or $(X, \Vert \cdot \Vert)$. But in finite dimensions, are norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent to begin with, which reduces much of the theory to calculus.

Comment: Halmos' "Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces" is quite popular but there could be others of course.

Comment: @tomasz It was my bad. I have been corrected it.